# Which table to put user account attributes in database table when using Devise?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using Rails as my framework for a web-application. I'm using Devise to setup authentication for my application. Devise automatically creates a user table, which includes columns such as email, password, etc.

Let's say I have a form in my application where a user submits a numerical value for points. Where would it be best to store this information in the database? Should I use the already existing user table created by Devise and add a "points" column to it? I'm just not sure if adjusting that table is best practice or not.

I am adhering to MVC practice for Rails by the way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

What are these points? A bit more clarity might help.

Considering another frequently required use-case might be useful ... let's say your user has a bunch of settings for your app, such as `locale`, `timezone`, `nickname`, `address`, etc.

Now, you could easily just add a ton of columns to your `users` table, and get things working, and arguably there's nothing wrong with that solution.

However, from both a code and data organisation perspective, it might be nicer to split things out a bit. For example, can anything else other than a `User` have an `Address`? Probably.

I like to keep my `User` model as simple as possible. Leave devise to do its thing with the users DB table, and organise the user's "things" into sensible places of their own:

- Create a `UserProfile` to store things like the `locale`, `timezone` and `nickname`
- Create an `Address` object and set up a polymorphic relationship to allow the `User` to be `addressable` ... you can then do the same thing with `Location`s, or anything else that requires an `Address`.

Splitting your code/data up in this way makes things easier to organise, test and maintain going forwards.